# Table Variable with Primary and Identity Key

Tags: sql-server, variables, primary-key, identity

I'm trying to enter a table variable with a primary key and identity key but I keep getting error "Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 313
An explicit value for the identity column in table '@Table4' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

Example of Code:
DECLARE @Table4 TABLE (ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1)
,DocumentNode VARCHAR(50)
,ModifiedDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @Table4
SELECT      ProductID, DocumentNode, ModifiedDate
FROM        [Production].[ProductDocument]

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table4

Comment: If you are talking about `sql` and particularly about MS `sql-server`, it might help to add those tags

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are specifying that ProductID is an identity column and then trying to insert a ProductID value. Remove IDENTITY(1,1) for it to work.